# Rails use collection_select to assign equipment to site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collection-select

I have a very simple rails application that collects "equipment" and assigns it to a "site"

```
    class CreateEquipment < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :equipment do |t|
      t.string :site_name
      t.string :equip_name
      t.string :equip_model
      t.string :equip_make
      t.string :equip_type
      t.belongs_to :site
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateSites < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :sites do |t|
      t.string :site_name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Two models "Equipment" and "Site"

```
class Equipment < ApplicationRecord

end

class Site < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :equipment

end
```

I have set up the equipment belongs_to Site and site has_many Equipment.

In my equipment form I have a collection_select to choose the site to assign the equipment too.

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :site_name %>
    <%= f.collection_select :site_name, Site.all, :site_name, :site_name, prompt: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :equip_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :equip_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :equip_model %>
    <%= f.text_field :equip_model %>
  </div>


<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :equip_make %>
    <%= f.text_field :equip_make %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :equip_type %>
    <%= f.text_field :equip_type %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and on the site show page, I have begun to set up the page to show equipment.

```
<p>
  <strong>Sitename:</strong>
  <%= @site.site_name %>
</p>

<% @site.equipment.each do |equipment| %>
  <p><%= equipment.equip_name %></p>
<% end %>
```

but I cannot see any equipment when I open the site show page.

I am not getting any faults or issues on the form or the page, I have allowed all params. I think I may have set up my collection_select incorrectly.

Update: Watching Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial Section 14.1.2 User/relationship associations and feel some enlightenment that anyone with this issue should get privy too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have learned alot over the time I have been playing with rails. Hopefully when a newbie finds this they will see the very simple error I made.

I didnt add the association to the site

```
class Equipment < ApplicationRecord

end

class Site < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :equipment

end
```

should be

```
class Equipment < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :site
end

class Site < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :equipment

end
```

and the table should change from

```
class CreateEquipment < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :equipment do |t|
      t.string :site_name
      t.string :equip_name
      t.string :equip_model
      t.string :equip_make
      t.string :equip_type
      t.belongs_to :site
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateEquipment < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :equipment do |t|
      t.string :equip_name
      t.string :equip_model
      t.string :equip_make
      t.string :equip_type
      t.references :site
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I hope that helps someone :)